# Different behavior for Dividers in Column

Tags: output-formatting

I just used `Column` with Dividers and found the following surprising (from the documentation of `Column`). Here Dividers at position 2 and 3, o.k.

```
Column[{1, 22, 333}, Dividers -> Center]
```

Now

```
Column[{1, 22, 333}, Dividers -> {Center, Blue}]
```

draws all Dividers. Is this a bug or a feature?
[image]

Comment: As `Column[{1, 22, 333}, Dividers -> {Red, Blue}]` reveals  the first spec in `{Center, Blue}`  refers to the column dividers and the second to row dividers. Maybe you need `Dividers -> {None, {None, {Blue}, None}}`  to make the internal  row dividers  `Blue`?

Comment: ref / Column / Details and Options: `{spec_x, spec_y} apply spec_i to successive horizontal and vertical gaps`.

Answer (score 1):

Form the Documentation, you can customize the `Dividers` as a feauture:

```
Column[{1, 22, 333}, Dividers -> {Center, {None, {2 -> Blue, 3 -> Blue}}}]
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen this but for me it is a bit inconsistent. If you have something like `Dividers->{...}` all Dividers are drawn (an you have to suppress them, bevor drawing what you want) and in other cases only intermediate ones are drawn.

Answer (score 0):

In `Column[{1, 22, 333}, Dividers -> {Center, Blue}]` reveals the first spec in `{Center, Blue}` applies to the column dividers and the second to row dividers.

To get only the inner dividers in `Blue`, you can use the setting `{None, {None, {Blue}, None}}`

```
Column[{1, 22, 333, 4444, 55555}, Dividers -> {None, {None, {Blue}, None}}]
```

[image]